# Two different Yammer share buttons on the same page

Tags: javascript, social-networking, yammer

Is it possible to add two different Yammer share buttons to the same page?

Using the documentation from [Yammer](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/share-button#) I was able to add two buttons to the same page, but they still point to the same url (http://example.com/button2 with the following configuration).

```
  yam.platform.yammerShare({
    customButton: true,
    classSelector: 'button1',
    pageUrl: 'http://example.com/button1'
  });
  yam.platform.yammerShare({
    customButton: true,
    classSelector: 'button2',
    pageUrl: 'http://example.com/button2'
  });
```

I also set up a full Plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/nkv4IvZlB2iA0ajbJWbm/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's an API to the event handler itself, so I could do the binding myself and gained the required flexibility:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button1')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  yam.platform.yammerShareOpenPopup({
    defaultMessage: 'Check out'
    pageUrl: 'http://example.com/button1
  });
});
document.getElementsByClassName('button2')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  yam.platform.yammerShareOpenPopup({
    defaultMessage: 'Check out',
    pageUrl: 'http://example.com/button2'
  });
});
```

This is also simpler when the urls are required to change, e.g. due to client-side routing. Check out a full Plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/KVpEsuj2DPISgrRU18nK/).